# Using dot operator with functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have just started learning `javascript` and `nodejs` by following a tutorial. One of the code they used is:

```
var express=require('express');
var app=express();
app.listen(3000);
```

Now when I do:

```
console.log(typeof app);
console.log(typeof app.listen);
```

I get:

```
function
function
```

as the output. Now if the `typeof app` is `function`, then how can we use `.` operator with it to access some other function(`listen`)? I tried to read the `express` module but couldn't understand much.

Can anyone give a simple example where we use a `function` name with `.` operator to access some other function inside it?

I tried this:

```
var t=function(){
    t.bar=function(){
        console.log('bar');
        }
    };  

t.bar();
```

But doesn't work.

Comment: You haven't defined `t.bar` in your example until you've called `t()`...

Comment: Functions are first-class citizens: `function a() {} a.some = function() { console.log('Some'); }`

Comment: @Tushar so can we use them just as we use `objects`?

Comment: Function ARE objects. :) So, yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functions are objects, and they can have properties just like any other object.

```
var t = function() {
    console.log('foo');
};

t.bar = function() {
    console.log('bar');
};

t.bar();

t.favColor = 'red';
t.shoeSize = 12;
```

Comment: Use the snippet, it makes the answer more reliable.

Answer (score 1):

In Javascript, `function`s are objects. This is how you can define an object:

```
var myObject = {/*Some members*/};
```

This is how you define a `function`

```
var myFunction = function(/*Some parameters*/) {/*Do something*/};

typeof myObject
```

will result in `"object"`

and

```
typeof myFunction
```

will result in `"function"`

The difference between them is that `myFunction` can be called, while `myObject` cannot be called. For example this

```
({})()
```

will result in an error. However, otherwise they are very similar, they can have members in the same way.

```
myFunction.myInnerFunction = function(/*Some other parameters*/) {/*Do something else*/};
```

assigns the `myInnerFunction` member of `myFunction` a value which happens to be a `function`. From there on you will be able to call `myFunction.myInnerFunction`. However, you will need to read more about `function`s, you may start your study with the [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) keyword.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is about basics of language.

There are lots of solutions.

It depends what You want to achieve.

Here are few examples:

```
const t = () => {}; 
t.bar = () => { 
    console.log('bar'); 
}; 

t.bar();
```

or:

```
const t = {
  bar: () => { 
    console.log('bar'); 
  }
};  

t.bar();
```

or:

```
class t {
  static bar() {
    console.log('bar'); 
  }
}

t.bar();
```

or:

```
class T {
  static bar() {
    console.log('bar'); 
  }
}

const t = new T();
t.bar();
```

and fix on Your example (same as in examples above):

```
var t = function {};
t.bar = function() { 
    console.log('bar'); 
};

t.bar();
```